# Specify a custom default value generating function in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm creating the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Symptoms] 
(
    [Id]          INT            NOT NULL,
    [description] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [imgPath]     NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [diseaseId] INT NOT NULL,
    [weight] FLOAT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC, [diseaseId] ASC)
);
```

What I want to do is create a default value for the `[imgPath]` column. I know about `DEFAULT newid()` and other methods, but I want a custom generated method.

Specifically, I want the `[imgPath]` to be `$"/resources/Images/{Id}_symptom.jpg"` where `Id` is the ID of that specific row.

Where can I specify this function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
Column defaults in SQL Server can't be made up using other columns data. 
What you can do is add another column for you to specify the image path, and use it as a part of the computed column's declaration:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Symptoms] (
    [Id]          INT            NOT NULL,
    [description] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [UserDefinedImgPath]     NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
    [imgPath] AS COALESCE(UserDefinedimgPath, '/resources/Images/' + CAST(Id AS NVARCHAR(13)) +'_symptom.jpg') PERSISTED,
    [diseaseId] INT NOT NULL,
    [weight] FLOAT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC, [diseaseId] ASC)
);
```

Now, when you want to specify the image page on insert or update, use the `UserDefinedImgPath` column. When you want the default value, simply leave it `null`.
When selecting the image path, always use the computed column.

**First answer**
Use a [computed column](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx) for `imgPath`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Symptoms] (
[Id]          INT            NOT NULL,
[description] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
[imgPath] AS '/resources/Images/' + CAST(Id AS NVARCHAR(13)) +'_symptom.jpg' PERSISTED,
[diseaseId] INT NOT NULL,
[weight] FLOAT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC, [diseaseId] ASC)
);
```

Note that you can't update a computed column, nor can you insert a specific value to it.

Comment: Is there any way to implement this such that the function is only carried out if the supplied value is null - i.e be able to insert whatever I want but have a default fallback?

Answer (score 0):

To add default value please create default constraint, in SQL Server the example is below:

```
 ALTER TABLE Symptoms 
     ADD CONSTRAINT Symptoms_imgPath 
     DEFAULT (('/resources/Images/{Id}_symptom.jpg')) FOR imgPath
```

Other way is to insert default value at the time of insert, like this:

```
INSERT INTO Symptoms 
    SELECT '/resources/Images/{Id}_symptom.jpg' 
    FROM symptoms 
    WHERE id = NEWID()
```

Comment: I don't think the top solution will interpolate the string as I would like... it will only set the string literal to be the default value. I want {Id} to be replaced by the Id of the specific Symptom

Comment: @Varun do you want  to replace '{Id}' ,the id with new id ?

Comment: Yes - {Id} should be the Id of the Symptom in that row